# Attribute being appending as query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to have multiple `attributesToIgnore`, so I configured it like:

```
attributesToIgnore="hideOnStandard, hideFormatting"
```

and my `Mvc.sitemap`:

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Filters" controller="Parameterized">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Filters" controller="Parameterized" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Output" controller="Parameterized" action="Output" preservedRouteParameters="id" hideOnStandard="true"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Formatting" controller="Parameterized" action="Formatting" preservedRouteParameters="id" hideFormatting="true" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

However, it appends the `hideFormatting="true"` to the query string for the anchor tag, like:

```
<a href="/Home/Reports/Formatting/29119?hideFormatting=true">Formatting</a>
```

How can I actually perform what I am trying to do? I've tried to delimit the `attributesToIgnore` differently, but other than that I'm not quite sure how else to go about it. I *really* don't want to use jQuery or something to strip the query string off.

### EDIT

How I know what to render :

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

<ul class="navProgress">
    @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
    {
        if (!(node.MetaAttributes.Keys.Contains("hideOnStandard") && TempData["IsStandard"] != null && ((bool)TempData["IsStandard"])))
        {
            if (!(node.MetaAttributes.Keys.Contains("hideFormatting") && TempData["hideFormatting"] != null && ((bool)TempData["hideFormatting"])))
            {
                <li @(node.IsCurrentNode ? "class=active" : "")>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
                @if (node.Children.Any())
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
                }
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Where are you configuring the attributes to ignore? In the `web.config` file or in a DI module?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yes, web.config, sorry about that. If you need the version or anything else let me know. Thanks

Comment: What version of `MvcSiteMapProvider` are you using? MetaAttributes has not been a valid property of SiteMapNode since v3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [MvcSiteMapProvider v3 documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/mvcsitemapprovider/wiki/Version-3.x-Documentation), `attributesToIgnore` should be added to the `<siteMap>` section of `web.config`.

```
<siteMap>
  <providers>
    <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap"
         securityTrimmingEnabled="true"
         cacheDuration="5"
         enableLocalization="true"
         scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true" 
         excludeAssembliesForScan="" 
         includeAssembliesForScan="" 
         attributesToIgnore="hideOnStandard,hideFormatting" 
         nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
         actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider"
         routeMethod=""
         siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

> I believe in v3.x, you also had to ensure there is not a space after the comma or it won't match the attribute correctly.

Use:

```
attributesToIgnore="hideOnStandard,hideFormatting"
```

Rather than:

```
attributesToIgnore="hideOnStandard, hideFormatting"
```

Comment: Let me edit my question to show you how we utilize the current `attributesToIgnore` and let me know if your answer is still the right direction.

Comment: If someone wonders where the sitemap-section should exactly be placed: configuration > system.web > sitemap